# How to sum Counter of Counter in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of which the elements are Counter of Counter. For example:

```
l = [Counter({'a': Counter({'aa': 1, 'bb': 2}), 'b': Counter({'aa': 3, 'cc':4})}),
     Counter({'a': Counter({'aa': 5, 'cc': 6}), 'c': Counter({'aa': 7, 'bb':8})})]
```

I wish to sum both Counters, that is, I wish to get the following result:

```
result = Counter({'a': Counter({'aa': 6, 'bb':2, 'cc': 6}),
                  'b': Counter({'aa': 3, 'cc':4}),
                  'c': Counter({'aa': 7, 'bb':8})})
```

To get this, I trid to sum `l` direcitly as follows,

```
result = sum(l, Counter())
```

but it retures the error,

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Counter' and 'int'.
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Do you have any code you tried to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new counter and add all your existing counter contents to it.
The dictionary class has a update method that can be used for this purpose:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [Counter({'a': Counter({'aa': 1, 'bb': 2}), 'b': Counter({'aa': 3, 'cc':4})}),
    Counter({'a': Counter({'aa': 5, 'cc': 6}), 'c': Counter({'aa': 7, 'bb':8})})]

result = Counter()

for counter in l:
    for key, value in counter.items():
        result.setdefault(key, Counter()).update(value) # update key by value's

print(result)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': Counter({'aa': 6, 'cc': 6, 'bb': 2}),
         'b': Counter({'cc': 4, 'aa': 3}),
         'c': Counter({'bb': 8, 'aa': 7})})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use collections' `defaultdict` as an accumulator instead of `Counter`:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

l = [Counter({'a': Counter({'aa': 1, 'bb': 2}), 'b': Counter({'aa': 3, 'cc':4})}),
     Counter({'a': Counter({'aa': 5, 'cc': 6}), 'c': Counter({'aa': 7, 'bb':8})})]

def aggregate_counters(acc, counter):
    extended = {x: acc[x] + counter[x] for x in counter}
    new_val = {**acc, **extended}
    return defaultdict(Counter, new_val)


reduce(aggregate_counters, l, defaultdict(Counter))
```

Will give:

```
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'a': Counter({'aa': 6, 'bb': 2, 'cc': 6}),
             'b': Counter({'aa': 3, 'cc': 4}),
             'c': Counter({'aa': 7, 'bb': 8})})
```

Comment: But it retures 'SyntaxError' at '**acc'.

Comment: You're probably using an outdated version of python. But the idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for beginners who doesn't have core knowledge all python dictionaries:

**Solution:**

```
l = [Counter({'a': Counter({'aa': 1, 'bb': 2}), 'b': Counter({'aa': 3, 'cc':4})}),
     Counter({'a': Counter({'aa': 5, 'cc': 6}), 'c': Counter({'aa': 7, 'bb':8})})]

returnval={}

for counters in l:
    for key, value in counters.items():
        if key not in returnval:
            returnval[key] = value
        else:
            returnval[key] = returnval[key].__add__(value)

print returnval
```

***Reference : https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter***

**Example:**
Add counts from two counters.

```
>>> Counter('abbb') + Counter('bcc')
Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})

>>> a=Counter({'aa': 1, 'bb': 2})
>>> b= Counter({'aa': 3, 'cc':4})
>>> print a.__add__(b)
Counter({'aa': 4, 'cc': 4, 'bb': 2})
```